# Why do not defining width on absolute positioned child get unusual behaviour?

Tags: css, width, css-position, absolute

Basically, I have 3 absolutely positioned elements within a relative container, one of them with `left: 100%` (the one coming next) and one with `left: -100%` (the previous picture). They transition between the available places automatically with the `transition` property. The final result of this can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0p2tuj22/show/).

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <article>
        <img>
    </article><article>
        <img>
    </article><article>
        <img>
    </article>
</div>
<style>
    div#slideshow   { position: relative; overflow: hidden }
    img             { width: 100%; height: auto }
    article         { width: 100%; position: absolute; transition: left 1s }
    article.current { left: 0 }
    article.prev    { left: -100% }
    article.next    { left: 100% }
</style>
```

*([This](http://jsfiddle.net/0p2tuj22/1/show/) is the result without `overflow: hidden` applied, to see how the slideshow works.)*

As you can see, the `<img>`s are responsive to their parent, `<article>`. I know that block elements always take the available width, so I didn't think I had to state it, but as you can see, I had to specify `width: 100%` on the `<article>`, too. What happens if I don't? [Something interesting, I'd say](http://jsfiddle.net/0p2tuj22/2/show/).

The `.prev` `<img>` turns twice as big as the others, and the `.next` `<img>` renders at size 0x0. What? You clearly see that all the image should have the same dimensions: 100% width, and auto height.

What I wanted to understand is; why does the CSS work like it does? I find this result quite unexpected, so I really wanted some kind of a discussion on why the result returns what it does, so that I could better understand how the underlying components of the CSS values actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not in the images themselves, but on the article.

It's the article elements that are ruling the dimensions, and image gets the dimensions from them.

The width of the article is not set. Lacking that, and in the presence of a *left* statement, a value of *right* 0px is assumed. So, when left is 0, the width is 100% of the container, when the left is -100% the width is 200%, and when the left is 100%, the width is 0.

How to solve this ?

1. Add a width: 100% to article. - the direct solution.
2. Instead of moving the articles with the left property, do it with a transform: translateX(-100%); You won't have the problem derived from changing left, and it is more performant

Comment: Thanks for replying. I now understand more regarding the `left`/`right`/`top`/`bottom` properties. I first tried adding the `right` property in addition to the `left`, but that didn't work, do you know why? Using CSS3 transforms is a great suggestion, something that I didn't think of before, and works gorgeously. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I think you mean that the value of `right` is assumed `700px`, not `0px`. That's at least what's happening in the demo.

Comment: No, 0px for right is ok. That means that the right is at 0px from the container right